# How to verify that the association is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called Profile which is belong_to User, so there is 'user_id' for the database to keep track of. In the local admin interface I made for this model I wanted to provide the flexibility of allowing admin to enter an username to a field in the editing screen, and then resolve that to user_id for saving in controller.

However the question is, how do I check against that the username have a valid return? I found that in ActiveRecord::Validation there is no method for validating the existence of the association. How will you handle a situation like this?

Update: What I want to do is to validate that the username field in the form is indeed a real user, then I could save that user_id back to the profile admin is editing. Here 'return' means the user object returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is a good candidate for virtual attributes.
Instead of trying to resolve the username, let the profile model to the job for you.

```
class Profile

  belongs_to :user

  # ...

  def username
    user.try(:username)
  end

  def username=(value)
    self.user = User.find_by_username(value)
  end

end
```

Then in your form

```
<% form_for @profile do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :username %>

<% end %>
```

When submitted, the value for the username field is automatically passed with all the other real activerecord attributes. ActiveRecord will look for the username= setter and will resolve the association.
If the association returns nil (no record exists with given username), then it will set current user_id to nil and validation will fail as expected.

You might want to customize the error code to make more meaningful.

EDIT: Added example.

```
validate :ensure_username_exists 

def username=(value) 
  self.user_id = User.find_by_username(value) || 0 
end 

protected 

  def ensure_username_exists 
    if user_id == 0 # nil is allowed 
      errors.add(:user_id, "Username doesn't exists") 
      return false 
    end
  end
```

Comment: How about if the user_id is optional? Which here a profile may be belonged to nobody.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. You might want to change username=() in order to return 0 in case the username doesn't exist, instead of nil. In this case you can check on save whether the value is == 0 and invalidate the object.

  validate :ensure_username_exists
  
  def username=(value)
    self.user_id = User.find_by_username(value) || 0
  end
  
  protected
  
    def ensure_username_exists
      if user_id == 0 # nil is allowed
        errors.add(:user_id, "Username doesn't exists")
        return false
      end
    end

This is just one possible solution.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote an example but it seems comments can't contain code. :S

Comment: @weppos you may try to put that example back to the answer.

Comment: did the `username=` means we overriding the default attr accs of rails/active record?

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful reference for Active Record Associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

To check for the existence of the association, just check *association*.nil?

```
if @profile.user.nil?
  ... something ...
end
```

To check if the username has a valid return, well I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you expand on that?

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to check a value for nil?. Use unless instead. So your example above would be: unless @profile.user; ..something; end